# AppDynamics TimeStamp Difference

Tags: timestamp, date-difference, app-dynamics-query-language

How to find TimeStamp difference in App Dynamics Query Language (ADQL)?

I tried column1 - column2. Getting error message "Operator **[SUBTRACTION]** not valid on field types **[DATETIME], [DATETIME]**.

Comment: well i might be mistaken but its worth a try, DATEDIFF(column1,column2) ? not sure but I remember it beeing based on oracles sql spec it might work

Comment: Already i tried this approach. DATADIFF is a unknown function in AppDynamic query language.

Comment: okay sorry for that, as said it was a rather wild guess